# Get high utilization CPU% + what service/process is causing it

Tags: time, counter, performancecounter, processor

I would like to know what service that is causing the high CPU utilization into the exisitng code below.
the code works well and sends noticication to me but i just need to add what process or service was high during that time. Thanks for the help!

```
while($true){
    if((Get-Counter -Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time").CounterSamples.CookedValue -ge 90){
        Send-MailMessage -Body "CPU is high at 90% on my PC" -From "MyPC@XXXXX" -SmtpServer "xxx.xxx.xxx" -Subject "CPU High on my PC" -To $recipients

    }
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-counter?view=powershell-7.3#example-14-sort-performance-counter-data

Comment: Are you sure you didn't want to put the sleep INSIDE the loop? The current code will just busy loop 100% of a single core.

Comment: sorry this is inside the loop, did paste the whole code

Comment: @Aron why would you think that? There is an opening brace for the `if`, and the closing brace we see belongs to that. There is only one closing brace missing, for the while ...

Comment: @derpirscher Didn't see a close brace after the sleep

Comment: @Aron there is none, but that doesn't mean the close brace before sleep belongs to the opening brace of the while ...